# Elements pushing web page aside?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs next to each other and is making the page larger and able to be scrolled to the side? Could anyone help with this? I've tried floating the divs and clearing them, but that has had no luck.

[image: Picture of site not working.]

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="options">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="cpc-courses">
                <h2 class="cpc-courses-h2"> Driver CPC Courses </h2>

                <img class="truck3"src="images/truck3.png">

                <p class="cpc-courses-para">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed      do eiusmod
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit. </p>

                <p class="read-more"> <a href="#"> Read More </a></p>
            </div>

        <div class="firstaid-courses">
            <h2 class="firstaid-courses-h2"> First Aid Courses </h2>

            <img class="truck3"src="images/firstaid.png">


            <p class="firstaid-courses-para">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit. </p>

            <p class="read-more"> <a href="#"> Read More </a></p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

.options {
    height: 504px;
    position: relative;
    top: 96px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.cpc-courses {
    padding: 40px;
}

.cpc-courses-h2 {
     font-family: Lato;
     font-weight: normal;
}

.cpc-courses-para {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 300px;
}

.firstaid-courses {
    padding: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: -476px;
    left: 500px;
}

.firstaid-courses-h2 {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: normal;
 }

 .firstaid-courses-para {
     font-family: Lato;
     font-weight: 300;
     width: 300px;
     margin: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: You need to plan your layout a lot more carefully. Just pushing elements around like you are is not going to produce a viable web page. Truly, you really need to read a beginner book on CSS. You won't regret it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix to your problem is to use `display: table`

I have updated your code into a working demo here - http://jsbin.com/dazemenunu/1/edit?html,css,output

To acheive this I

- Removed the `position: relative;` rules

And replaced with

- `display: table` on the .wrapper
- `display: table-cell` on the `.cpc-courses` and `.firstaid-courses` classes

A better overall solution would be to use a responsive layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is overflow for the scroll bars

```
overflow: hidden // Wrapper
```

then you should be able to float the other divs

```
float: left // float both divs left
```

You shouldnt need the negative top item.

another route is to go with

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

I would look at those options to stack them. Hope that helps.

Added a codepen to show the minimalist usage of inline block without float. http://codepen.io/sixthcore/pen/WbXdOd